# Is there any way to change the layer order of elements inside of a canvas through a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to show certain elements in front of others depending on the situation, but I would like to keep them inside the same canvas.
The only sort of layer order that I could find is the order in which they are placed in the canvas, but this can't be modified by code as far as I know.
I would like to know if there is any line of code that allows me to modify the layer order of elements inside of a canvas in any way possible.

Comment: YourObject.Transform.SetSiblingIndex or something like that

Comment: Thank you very much @John that was exactly what I needed